# How I prepend a string on each item of an array?

Tags: bash

I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

items=('mysql_apache','postgresql_apache','maria_apache')
string=""
for i in "${array[@]}"; do
    string=$string" -t"$i
done

echo $string
```

But if I output the string I won't get the expected result:

```
-t 'mysql_apache' -t 'postgresql_apache' -t 'maria_apache'
```

DO you have any Idea how I can do this?

## Edit 1

I tried the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

items=('mysql_apache' 'postgresql_apache' 'maria_apache')
string=""
for i in "${array[@]}"; do
    string=$string" -t"$i
done

echo $string
```

But I still do not get the expected output.

Comment: Array elements are separated by spaces, not commas.

Comment: `items=('mysql_apache' 'postgresql_apache' 'maria_apache')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array elements are separated by whitespace, not commas. Also, `items` != `array`.

```sh
#! /bin/bash

items=(mysql_apache postgresql_apache maria_apache)
string=""
for i in "${items[@]}"; do
    string+=" -t $i"
done

echo $string
```

But you don't need a loop at all:

```sh
items=(mysql_apache postgresql_apache maria_apache)
echo ${items[@]/#/-t }
```

The substitution can be applied to every element of an array. The `/#` matches at the start of each string.

Comment: BTW, this will misbehave with array elements that contain whitespace. If the command allows you to pass the option (`-t`) and its argument together (most commands allow this), you can use `somecommand "${items[@]/#/-t}"` (note the double-quotes and lack of space after `-t`).

Answer (score 1):

You're close.  Your forgot to change ${array[@]} in the for loop to what your array was named: items or specifically ${items[@]}  You also needed a few other little changes, see below:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a items=('mysql_apache' 'postgresql_apache' 'maria_apache')
string=""
for i in "${items[@]}"; do
    string=${string}" -t "$i
done

echo $string
```

Lastly if you want to see what is happening you can add temporary echo statements to see what if anything is changing:

```
for i in "${items[@]}"; do
    string=${string}" -t "$i
echo >>>$string<<<
done
```

Comment: Embedding literal quotes in your data (as in `"'mysql_apache'"`) is almost always a mistake. It'll look right when `echo`ed, but won't actually work the way you might expect. See ["Why does shell ignore quoting characters in arguments passed to it through variables?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quotes-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-variables)

Comment: Great point Gordon, thank you.  I've edited my answer to correct that.